# How to run a Jenkins job with fixed parameters

Tags: jenkins, automation

I have a Jenkins Job that runs tests on a certain software. It has parameters:

- git branch of the software to be tested
- git branch of the test framework
- list of test cases to execute

It produces a nice Junit report for the passed test cases. Some of them fail, some of them pass. I want to establish a baseline to smoke-test further development. I want a new Jenkins job that executes this one with a fixed list of test cases. This "smoke test job" will have its own plot with all the Junit results passed.

I though about just cloning the current job and hardcode the list of test cases to the ones I know they pass, but it will be more difficult to maintain because further changes will have to be done in both jobs.

Is there any idea how can I achieve it by establishing a dependency between both jobs and only configure the list of test cases in the "smoke test job"?